# jwt connection from angular project to jhipster

Tags: java, angular, jhipster

i have an angular basic project and a simple microservice jhipster project. since i chosed jwt option in my jhipster project , i want to consume methods from my angular project.after looking for hours i finnaly found this code which helped me to connect successfuly but i get a weird error which bloked me. here is my angular classes i used to try connect and consume jhipster methods:

auth-interceptor.ts file

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private token: TokenStorageService) { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    let authReq = req;
    const token = this.token.getToken();
    if (token != null) {
        authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + token) });
    }
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
 }

 export const httpInterceptorProviders = [
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
];
```

auth.service.ts

```
 const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };



 @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class AuthService {

      private loginUrl = 'http://localhost:8082/api/authenticate';
      private signupUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signup';

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      }

      attemptAuth(credentials: AuthLoginInfo): Observable<JwtResponse> {
       return this.http.post<JwtResponse>(this.loginUrl, credentials, httpOptions);
        }

       signUp(info: SignUpInfo): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post<string>(this.signupUrl, info, httpOptions);
       }
     }
```

jwt-response.ts

```
export class JwtResponse {
   accessToken: string;
   type: string;
    username: string;
   authorities: string[];
  }
```

token-storage.service.spec.ts

```
describe('TokenStorageService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [TokenStorageService]
   });
   });

   it('should be created', inject([TokenStorageService], (service: TokenStorageService) => {
     expect(service).toBeTruthy();
   }));
  });
```

token.storage.service.ts

```
  const TOKEN_KEY = 'AuthToken';
     const USERNAME_KEY = 'AuthUsername';
     const AUTHORITIES_KEY = 'AuthAuthorities';

     @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenStorageService {
  private roles: Array<string> = [];
  constructor() { }

  signOut() {
    window.sessionStorage.clear();
  }

  public saveToken(token: string) {
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY, token);
  }

  public getToken(): string {
    return sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);
  }

  public saveUsername(username: string) {
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(USERNAME_KEY);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(USERNAME_KEY, username);
  }

  public getUsername(): string {
    return sessionStorage.getItem(USERNAME_KEY);
  }

  public saveAuthorities(authorities: string[]) {
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(AUTHORITIES_KEY);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(AUTHORITIES_KEY, JSON.stringify(authorities));
  }

  public getAuthorities(): string[] {
    this.roles = [];

    if (sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY)) {
      JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(AUTHORITIES_KEY)).forEach(authority => {
        this.roles.push(authority.authority);
      });
       }

       return this.roles;
      }
     }
```

and finnaly this is my connection method:

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form);

    this.loginInfo = new AuthLoginInfo(
      this.form.username,
      this.form.password);

    this.authService.attemptAuth(this.loginInfo).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.tokenStorage.saveToken(data.accessToken);
        this.tokenStorage.saveUsername(data.username);
        this.tokenStorage.saveAuthorities(data.authorities);

        this.isLoginFailed = false;
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this.roles = this.tokenStorage.getAuthorities();
        this.reloadPage();
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.errorMessage = error.error.message;
        this.isLoginFailed = true;
      }
    );
  }
```

with this i am able to login successfully but once i login i get this error when i try to do anything else:

```
core.js:6014 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at TokenStorageService.getAuthorities (token-storage.service.ts:45)
```

Guys if u know any simple method to connect to jhipster using jwt from angular please help me cause i am blocked here , i have a full jhipster project which i cant consume any..

Comment: That error says your jwt is malformed.

Comment: can you tell me how to fix please

Comment: Get a valid, not-malformed JWT ...?

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems your server does not provide `authorities` in the JWT response. Since the data is missing, the `saveAuthorities` saves string `"undefined"` that cannot be served later.

If the reason `authorities` is missing is that you blindly copied some random code off the internet, delete the `authorities` from `class JwtResponse` and `saveAuthorities`, `getAuthorities` and all references to them.

Otherwise, just provide the `authorities` in your response.

Or you can check if authorities exist when saving them in `onSubmit` callback.

```
if (data.authorities)
    this.tokenStorage.saveAuthorities(data.authorities);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your condition in the `getAuthorities` method. The token is undefined. The error you have comes from trying to parse `undefined` in `JSON.parse(...)`. You check the `TOKEN_KEY` in storage but read `AUTHORITIES_KEY`

Your code:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY)) {
  JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(AUTHORITIES_KEY)).forEach(authority => {
```

Correct code:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem(AUTHORITIES_KEY)) {
  JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(AUTHORITIES_KEY)).forEach(authority => {
```

Comment: thanks for reponse but i changed it like you said i still get same error man

Comment: Try clearing the storage (DevTools -> Application -> Clear storage), you might have some invalid data in there.

Comment: Oh, you're saving undefined in there.